# In Delphi should I use multiple database inserts from within a loop or use a stored procedure?

Tags: database, delphi, stored-procedures, loops

I'm looking for the best way to handle this situation. I want to store an amortization schedule inside a databse table. Each row contains the date, current balance, payment, pricipal, interest, and new balance. For a typical 30 year mortgage this would be 360 rows or database inserts.

Should I do the calculations inside a loop using Delphi and do an insert for each result or should I perform these calculations inside a stored procedure?

This would be a single user, local machine, desktop application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do the operations in the stored procedure. That way working with data is in the database where it belongs.

Also, by keeping all data related operations in the database you save yourself the hassle of coding it again if sometime in the future you choose to switch language.

Comment: I'm coming from a world of customers locked into Oracle so DBMS change is next to impossible:). IMHO, having all data related operations (SELECTs for one, but mostly specific operations that include modifying one or more tables) should be in the database where they belong. Storing the business rules in a database and exposing them through custom APIs also. Admittedly, this will increase the learning curve for a programmer responsible but I think it's worth it. I admit this probably comes down to the size of application and preferences of people who are working on it :)

Comment: @Miho, yes, it is a personal preference, but one that would kill me if someone did it on one of my projects. For an application developer, the use of stored procedures is a viper's nest! Essentially it moves the data rules out of the scope of the application developer and pushes them out of sight. I like to know what is going on with the data, not have it mysteriously appear for me.

Comment: @Misha, I agree with you about data just appearing. People working with data need to know what and how is retrieved or processed. The problem is the distinction between application developer and database developer. I don't get how something is mysteriously appearing in your code. If we put something in a stored procedure, that doesn't mean that an application developer can't locate and modify/view that procedure? It just add another abstraction level. A good (although DB biased) view: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2143974700346554115

Comment: @Miho, the distinction between database developer and application developer is more a tools preference than a role-based one. As an applcation developer I design the databases as well, but I come from an OO background, not a data-based one. Yes, another abstraction level is good, but if it is in code I can see it right there as I develop, while if it is in stored procedures the code is "hidden" in a separate development environment, the database schema. All things being equal, I want all the "code" in one place.

Comment: @Misha, Let's just agree to disagree on this particular segment :)

Comment: I used to do this way (stored procs for logic) in a former job. I really hated maintaining it after a while.

Comment: Miho: that is the "stepping up to the DBA role" bit. I'm from a different world where a db delivered by a vendor should simply have low maintenance overhead and should never become a problem. A dumb transactional store with backup option so to say. And without a dba on site, I prefer to solve the problems in my software.

Answer (score 8):

Prepared queries and stored procedures are comparable performance-wise. As an application developer I detest stored procedures with a passion because they move logic from inside the application, where I can find it, to somewhere else not visible when looking through the source code. And let's face it, nobody is going to redevelop an application in a different language if it works.

So, if your thing is databases and SQL and you are comfortable with that, then stored procedures are fine. However, if you are primarily an application developer, I cannot see any benefit of using stored procedures over having the queries executed from code.

Comment: What is a "Prepared Query" and how would you use one in a Delphi application?

Comment: A prepared query is a parameterised query which has had resources "allocated" (prepared) on the server for better performance. You can then run the same query multiple times and it is only "setup" (prepared) once on the server. Look for a Prepared property on the query components you are using (ADO, dbExpress, etc).

Comment: If the source data was is already in the database, and the destination is the Same Database.   Then a Stored procedure is the only way to go, otherwise you had network performance to the mix and slow down the operation.

Comment: @Robert, only if you have a slow network and a lot of data. Most database access these days is over gigabit ethernet across a LAN, and there is usually more processing power available on the client than the server (which is of course shared by lots of clients). So the conditions for this being the case are not that common and data is usually entered by the user or comes from another external source. Add to this the added power and maintainability of a more structured and flexible language than SQL like Delphi. I just cannot see how keeping it in the database is an advantage.

Comment: I use an Oracle Server 128GB RAM, and several CPU's, attached to a wickedly fast disk array.  I have to deal with operations with millions of rows.    In our situation,  It's by far faster to keep the data on the server.   Every time I catch a developer moving it to the local machine, we convert the code and get HUGE performance gains.

Comment: @Robert, I would suggest that you have a specialised need to crunch the data, and that most developers do not access a database that needs 128GB of RAM. Given your parameters stored procedures are obviously the way to go. However, the OP's database is a bit lower spec'd (single user, local machine, desktop application) ;-)

Comment: @Misha - I'm just now returning to Delphi after an 8 year absense. During those 8 years I spent my time developing web based applications utilizing MS SQL Server and Classic ASP.  So, I learned how to think in terms of limiting the number of I/O's and server round trips. I forced myself to find SQL solutions to programming challenges that could have been handled much easier by the application language. It's probably easier to write the code in Delphi but it's probably more scaleable if I put the code in a Stored Procedure. In my case I own all the processes. However, I understand your points.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to use [AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac), it supports ArrayDML for all their supported databases. I think this is one nifty feature. This is commercial software, but a very good investment. (I'm not associated to them in any way, except as a very satisfied customer.)

See [Very High Performance using the Array DML](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/docu/Very_High_Performance_using_the_Array_DML.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your database is local and you don't plant to make it client/server one day there could be little difference from a performance perspective. Much depends on what database you use.
Some have "array DML" which would allow you to perform all the 360 inserts in one database round-trip, basically instead of doing 360 inserts you fill array bind variables and perform a single insert. The worst way would anyway be using n inserts without bind variables.
Compiled and optimized Delphi code may be somewhat faster than a interpreted stored procedure code, if the database doesn't compile it (some may just use P-Code).
From a design perspective, putting the data logic inside the DB publishing a sort of API via stored procedures (may forbidding other ways to modify data) may ensure a stronger control over data.